# Null pointer dereference bug while pointer was not null recently

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am writing Linux kernel module and have some problem:
my module falls in point after checking these pointer value

```
static struct area_control {
    struct list_head head;
    unsigned long addr;
    unsigned long jiffies;
    struct area_part *part;
} *const_areas = NULL, *var_areas = NULL;

static struct area_control *Find_Area(unsigned long addr, struct area_control *first_area)
{
    if (first_area)
    {
        struct area_control *cur_area = first_area;
        while ( 1 ) 
        {
            if (!cur_area) return NULL;
            if (cur_area->addr == addr)
            {
                cur_area->jiffies = jiffies;
                return cur_area;
            }
            cur_area = list_entry(cur_area->head.next, struct area_control, head);
            if (cur_area == first_area) return NULL;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

at point 
`cur_area->head.next` 
module falls because cur_area is NULL! - this fact I got from call trace and disassembler. Module for Linux 2.6.34 x86_64 multiprocessor architecture

Comment: What line are you talking about?

Comment: What are you passing as the 2nd argument to list_entry?

Comment: Your third argument makes no sense either since it's not declared anywhere that I can see...

Comment: @Jason `list_entry` is probably a macro. `head` is one of the members in `struct area_control`.

Comment: @melpomene Okay, well, I think it would be important to have the macro definition then ...

Comment: @Jason And/or the assembler code.

Comment: Yes, `list_entry` is macro defined in linux kernel headers. To Kerrek SB: I talk about line `cur_area = list_entry(cur_area->head.next, struct area_control, head)`

Comment: these line in assembler is pretty simple: `mov     rax, [rbp+cur_area]; mov     rax, [rax]`. Code falls on second instruction

Comment: Is this the only thread you have running, or is it possible something else has stomped over this area of memory?

Comment: I use spinlock, so another process formally can't acces this data

Comment: IMO `cur_area` is not NULL (so many tests before to reach that line) OR you have a *stack* problem (eg overflow of another param etc...). `cur_area` could simply point to an invalid area (access protected or out of bounds) while not null...

Answer (score 0):

```
        cur_area = list_entry(cur_area->head.next, struct area_control, head);
```

**You need to check if  `cur_area->head.next` is `NULL` as well.**

Using the macro definition:

```
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
((type *)((char *)(ptr) – (unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))
```

the code will be expanded to:

```
        cur_area = ((struct area_control *)((char *)(cur_area->head.next) - (unsigned long(&((struct area_control *)0)->head)))
```

As you can see, this code will fail if `cur_area->head.next` is null.

Comment: there can't be null-valued fields `prev` and `next` in linux double-linked list if elements were initialized in right way. also you can see disassembled code `mov rax, [rbp+cur_area]; mov rax, [rax]` of these macro-definition `list_entry` - these code works well ethen though the walue `cur_area->head.next` is NULL

Comment: It seems to me (based on the information in your question) that `cur_area->head.next` is `NULL`. How it became `NULL` I cannot say. Probably a bug somewhere in the rest of code. I would set a breakpoint on when it is changed in the debugger.

Comment: `cur_area->head.next` can have any value at these line without fatal consequences. Bug 'null pointer dereference' says that `cur_area` (not cur_area->head.hext as you say) is NULL. also call trace says the same: %rax=0x0000 at error point

Comment: Maybe the error message generation is confused by the casts? You say that `cur_area->head.next` shouldn't be `NULL`. Run it in the debugger again and check the value.